# Calabi $C^3$ estimate

Tags: riemannian-geometry, elliptic-pde, kahler-manifolds, calabi-yau

I have a question regarding a computation analogous to the Calabi $C^3$ estimate which is used in the proof of the Calabi--Yau theorem.

---

**Motivation:** Establishing Liouville type theorems for complex Monge--Ampère equations on compact Kähler manifolds which do not have definite or trivial first Chern class.

---

Let us proceed as usual:

Set $$S = \left| \Psi \right|^2 = g^{\overline{j} i} g^{\overline{q} p} g_{k \overline{\ell}} \Psi_{ip}^k \overline{\Psi_{jq}^{\ell}},$$ where $$\Psi_{ij}^k \ : = \ \Gamma_{ij}^k - \hat{\Gamma}_{ij}^k \ = \ g^{\overline{\ell} k} \hat{\nabla}_i g_{j \overline{\ell}}.$$

A well-known calculation shows that \begin{eqnarray*}
\Delta S &=& 2 \text{Re} \left( g^{\overline{j} i} g^{\overline{q} p} g_{k \overline{\ell}}(\Delta \Psi_{ip}^k) \overline{\Psi_{jq}^{\ell}} \right) + \left| \overline{\nabla} \Psi \right|^2 + \left| \nabla \Psi \right|^2 \\
&& + R^{\overline{j} i} g^{\overline{q} p} g_{k \overline{\ell}} \Psi_{ip}^k \overline{\Psi_{jq}^{\ell}} + g^{\overline{j} i} R^{\overline{q}p} g_{k \overline{\ell}} \Psi_{ip}^k \overline{\Psi_{jq}^{\ell}} - g^{\overline{j} i} g^{\overline{q} p} R_{k \overline{\ell}} \Psi_{ip}^k \overline{\Psi_{jq}^{\ell}}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Of course, in general, we have no control of the Ricci curvature of $g$. In the Calabi--Yau case, however, the Ricci curvature vanishes and we see that $$\Delta S = 2 \text{Re} \left( g^{\overline{j} i} g^{\overline{q} p} g_{k \overline{\ell}}(\Delta \Psi_{ip}^k) \overline{\Psi_{jq}^{\ell}} \right) + \left| \overline{\nabla} \Psi \right|^2 + \left| \nabla \Psi \right|^2.$$

---

**Q1.** The first term in the above expression for $\Delta S$ is also killed off if one assumes $g$ is Ricci flat. I would like some help seeing this.

---

Assuming the first term is also killed off, then $$\Delta S = \left| \overline{\nabla} \Psi \right|^2 + \left| \nabla \Psi \right|^2.$$ Choose now a cutoff function $\rho$ which is supported in $B_{2R}$, is identically 1 on $B_R$, and satisfies $$\left| \nabla \rho \right|_{g}^2 \leq C R^{-2}, \ \ \  \ \ \ \Delta^{g}(\rho^2) \geq - C R^{-2}.$$

Then \begin{eqnarray*}
\Delta^g(\rho^2 S) & \geq & \rho^2(\left| \nabla \Psi \right|^2 + \left| \overline{\nabla} \Psi \right|_g^2 ) - CR^{-2}S - 2 \left| \langle \nabla \rho^2, \nabla S \rangle_g \right| \\
& \geq & - CR^{-2}S,
\end{eqnarray*}
where we have used Young's inequality to assert that \begin{eqnarray*}
2 \left| \langle \nabla \rho^2, \nabla S \rangle \right| &=& 4 \rho \left| \langle \nabla \rho, \nabla \left| \Psi \right|_g^2 \rangle_g \right| \\
& \leq & C \rho \left| \nabla_g \left| \Psi \right|_g^2 \right|_g \\
& \leq & \rho^2 ( \left| \nabla \Psi \right|_g^2 + \left| \overline{\nabla} \Psi \right|_g^2 ) + CS.
\end{eqnarray*}

---

**Goal:** The main estimate I am attempting to obtain is $$\Delta (\rho^2 S) \geq - CR^{-2} S.$$

---

Consider now the case when $g$ is not Ricci-flat, but satisfies some twisted Kähler-Einstein equation of the form $$\text{Ric}_g = - g + h,$$ where $h$ is another Kähler metric. Replicating the aforementioned "well-known" computation, we see that \begin{eqnarray*}
\Delta S &=& 2 \text{Re} \left( g^{\overline{j} i} g^{\overline{q} p} g_{k \overline{\ell}}(\Delta \Psi_{ip}^k) \overline{\Psi_{jq}^{\ell}} \right) + \left| \overline{\nabla} \Psi \right|^2 + \left| \nabla \Psi \right|^2 \\
&& + \left( -g^{\overline{b} a} - g^{\overline{j} a} g^{\overline{b} i} h_{i \overline{j}} \right)  g^{\overline{q} p} g_{k \overline{\ell}} \Psi_{ip}^k \overline{\Psi_{jq}^{\ell}} + g^{\overline{j} i} \left( - g^{\overline{b} a} - g^{\overline{q} a} g^{\overline{b} p} h_{p \overline{q}} \right) g_{k \overline{\ell}} \Psi_{ip}^k \overline{\Psi_{jq}^{\ell}} \\
&& - g^{\overline{j} i} g^{\overline{q} p} \left( - g_{k \overline{\ell}} + h_{k \overline{\ell}}  \right) \Psi_{ip}^k \overline{\Psi_{jq}^{\ell}} \\
&=& 2 \text{Re} \left( g^{\overline{j} i} g^{\overline{q} p} g_{k \overline{\ell}}(\Delta \Psi_{ip}^k) \overline{\Psi_{jq}^{\ell}} \right) + \left| \overline{\nabla} \Psi \right|^2 + \left| \nabla \Psi \right|^2 \\
&& - g^{\overline{b}a} g^{\overline{q} p} g_{k \overline{\ell}} \Psi_{ip}^k \overline{\Psi_{jq}^{\ell}} - g^{\overline{j} a} g^{\overline{b} i} h_{i \overline{j}}  g^{\overline{q} p} g_{k \overline{\ell}} \Psi_{ip}^k \overline{\Psi_{jq}^{\ell}} - g^{\overline{j} i} g^{\overline{b}a} g_{k \overline{\ell}} \Psi_{ip}^k \overline{\Psi_{jq}^{\ell}} \\
&& - g^{\overline{j} i} g^{\overline{q} a} g^{\overline{b} p} h_{p \overline{q}} g_{k \overline{\ell}} \Psi_{ip}^k \overline{\Psi_{jq}^{\ell}} + g^{\overline{j} i} g^{\overline{q} p} g_{k \overline{\ell}} \Psi_{ip}^k \overline{\Psi_{jq}^{\ell}} - g^{\overline{j} i} g^{\overline{q} p} h_{k \overline{\ell}} \Psi_{ip}^k \overline{\Psi_{jq}^{\ell}}
\end{eqnarray*}

---

**Q2.** At this point, I am stuck. I am not sure these terms involving the metric $h$ can be controlled to obtain an estimate of the above form, or perhaps even an estimate of the form $$\Delta S \geq - C_1 S - C_2.$$

Comment: Q1 is wrong. The correct statement is that the first term vanishes if $g$ is Ricci flat and $\hat{g}$ is flat.